# Why does the implementation of declval in libstdc++-v3 look so complicated?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype, declval

The code below comes from libstdc++-v3 [`std::type_traits`](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/type_traits.html#759), which is an implementation of `std::declval`:

```cpp
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Up = _Tp&&> // template 1
    _Up
    __declval(int);
  template<typename _Tp> // template 2
    _Tp
    __declval(long);
  template<typename _Tp> // template 3
    auto declval() noexcept -> decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0));
```

But I think I can implement `declval` as simply:

```cpp
template <typename T> T declval();
```

Here is my test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct C {
    C() = delete;
    int foo() { return 0; }
};

namespace test {
template <typename T> T declval();
};// namespace test

int main() {
    decltype(test::declval<C>().foo()) n = 1;
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Build and run commands are:

```sh
g++ -std=c++11 ./test.cpp
./a.out
```

1. Why does the implementation in libstdc++-v3 look so complicated?
2. What does template 1 in the first snippet do?
3. Why does `__declval` need a parameter (`int`/`long`)?
4. Why do template 1 (`int`) and template 2 (`long`) have different parameter types?
5. Are there any problems with my simple implementation?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is actually:

```cpp
template<class T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;
```

Where [`std::add_rvalue_reference<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) is usually `T&&`, except in cases where that is invalid (Like if `T = void` or `T = int() const`), where it is just `T`. The main difference is that functions cannot return arrays, but can return array references like `U(&&)[]` or `U(&&)[N]`.

The problem with explicitly using `std::add_rvalue_reference` is that it instantiates a template. And that itself instantiates around 10s of templates at an instantiation depth of ~4 in the libstdc++ implementation. In generic code, `std::declval` can be used a lot, and according to https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27798, there is a >4% compile time boost by not using `std::add_rvalue_reference`. (The libc++ implementation instantiates less templates, but it still has an impact)

This is fixed by inlining the "`add_rvalue_reference`" directly into `declval`. This is done using SFINAE.

---

The return type for `declval<T>` is `decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0))`. When looking up `__declval`, two function templates are found.

The first has return type `_Up = T&&`. The second just has return type `T`.

The first takes a parameter `int`, and the second `long`. It is being passed `0`, which is an `int`, so the first function is a better match and is chosen, and `T&&` is returned.

Except, when `T&&` is not a valid type (e.g., `T = void`), then when the template argument `_Up` is substituted with the deduced `T&&`, there is a substitution failure. So it is no longer a candidate for the function. That means only the second one is left, and the `0` is converted into a long (And the return type is just `T`).

In cases where `T` and `T&&` can't be returned from a function (e.g., `T = int() const`), neither function can be picked, and the `std::declval<T>` function has a substitution failure and is not a viable candidate.

---

Here is the libc++ commit introducing the optimisation: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/ae7619a8a358667ea6ade5050512d0a27c03f432

And here is the libstdc++ commit: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=ec26ff5a012428ed864b679c7c171e2e7d917f76

They were both previously `std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`

Comment: But... why the second template parameter with default argument rather than `_Tp&&`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Doesn't seem to be any particular reason. libstdc++ implements it with a `_Tp&&` return type. The rest of the type traits in libc++ use unnamed `bool = SFINAE_stuff` or `typename = SFINAE_stuff`, so maybe for consistency? Doesn't matter either way

Answer (score 19):

This is to catch types where references can't be formed. In particular, `void`.

Usually the `int` overload is chosen. If `_Tp` is `void`, the `int` overload will fail by `_Up = void&&`, and then the `long` overload is chosen.

Your implementation doesn't add references, which fails with arrays and functions.

```
test::declval<void()>() // fails
```